# asp.net core - AutoValidateAntiforgeryTokenAttribute vs AutoValidateAntiforgeryTokenAuthorizationFilter

Tags: action-filter, antiforgerytoken, asp.net-core-2.0

In an asp.net core 2.0 project, I found these 2  filters when I plan to add a global filter. Which one should I add?

```
AutoValidateAntiforgeryTokenAttribute
```

or

```
AutoValidateAntiforgeryTokenAuthorizationFilter
```

what's the difference between them?

```
    services.AddMvc(options =>
    {
        // Adds global filters.
        options.Filters.Add(/*?????*/);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

`AutoValidateAntiforgeryTokenAuthorizationFilter` is the service `AutoValidateAntiforgeryTokenAttribute` uses to do it's thing. Use the attribute, not the filter.